# IOS - Как считать состояние пикселя с CALayer?

Tags: ios

Задача - посчитать в слое количество непрозрачных пикселей.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как взять состояние пикселя с CALayer.

UPD: по мере разбора задачи, ситуация осложнилась. В слое, который нужно оценить, присутствует не только родная альфа, но присвоевоена битмап-маска.

UPD2: Эксперименты разных кусков кода родили вот такое решение задачи, работает в общем устойчиво.

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageRef inImage = [outputImage CGImage];

UIColor* color = nil;
//CGImageRef inImage = self.image.CGImage;
// Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
// raw image data in the specified color space.
CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage);

// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.
int OpacityCount = 0;
int RedCount = 0;int GreenCount = 0;int BlueCount = 0;
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) {
    //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
    //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
    //int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    for (int i=0; i<w; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<h; j++){
            int offset = 4*((w*j)+round(i));
            int alpha =  data[offset];
            int red = data[offset+1];
            int green = data[offset+2];
            int blue = data[offset+3];
            if (alpha != 0) {OpacityCount++;
                //NSLog(@"координаты: x %i y %i",i,j);
                //NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
            }
            if (red != 0) RedCount++; if (green != 0) GreenCount++; if (blue != 0) BlueCount++;
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }}
    NSLog(@"непрозрачных %i RGB %i %i %i",OpacityCount,RedCount,GreenCount,BlueCount);
}

// When finished, release the context
CGContextRelease(cgctx);
// Free image data memory for the context
if (data) { free(data); }

//return color;
return outputImage;
}

- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage {

CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
void *          bitmapData;
int             bitmapByteCount;
int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

// Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

// Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
// example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
// alpha.
bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

// Use the generic RGB color space.
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

if (colorSpace == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
    return NULL;
}

// Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
// where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
//bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount ); //в памяти плавает всякая кака
bitmapData = calloc( pixelsWide*pixelsHigh, 4 ); //метод с очисткой памяти
if (bitmapData == NULL)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return NULL;
}

// Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
// per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
// (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
// specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,      // bits per component
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
if (context == NULL)
{
    free (bitmapData);
    fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
}

// Make sure and release colorspace before returning
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

return context;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Погуглил на стеке вот что нашел, незнаю то или нет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354632/887325
Вот еще по теме вроди бы: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

Comment: Спасибо за линки, во всем этом тоже есть зерно. На решение меня натолкнуло несколько постов ключевой из которых этот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics

Comment: И тебе спасибо может кому пригодится ;)